# Connect using specific IP (multiple IPs on NIC)

Tags: c#, sockets, ip

I have multiple IPs on a NIC. I've programmed a console application to connect to a socket - this connection is made by a specific IP.

Is it possible to tell which IP this connection should use, because I have multiple IP's assigned to my server?

Hope I made this clear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Socket.Bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx) is your friend.